# Oracle - count() in same line

Tags: sql, oracle, matrix, count

i'm new user here, and i think that this is amazing!!!
I need a little help:

i do this, but don't work like i want! (count(countOfCat) is no Good!)

```
select count(countOfCat) as "Cat", count(countOfDog) as "dog", count(countOfHorse) as "horse", 0 as "duck", 0 as "Mouse"
from animal
where Birthdate in
        (...
         -- i think not important
         ...
        )
        and ( species= 'cat' or species= 'dog' or species= 'horse')
group by species
```

i'm want to receive like this

```
Cat     Dog     Horse   Duck   mouse
------- ------- ------- ------  -------
1234    2345    3456     0      0
```

...

I need that all count are in the same row.
I can't utilize this

```
noGood- Cat   Dog     Horse   Duck    mouse
noGood- ----- ------ -------- ------- -------
noGood- 1234  0       0       0         0
noGood- 0     2345    0       0         0
noGood- 0     0       3456    0         0
```

Thank you for yout time!
Da!

Comment: Can you provide sample data of the original table please?

Comment: is "species" is your column name?? and "cat","dog" and "horse" is your value of the that column ??

Comment: @ Yagnesh: Yes species is a column name, and yes cat dog and horse are (a substring of) my values specie's column. 
Thank
@ Daryl: this is a little translate of a Big System, i need to put this select in a materilized view, but i hope that is enough know that i have a big table: "animal" with a column like "species", and cat dog horse duck are the values of species.
i have another important colum that is "birthdate"  and i have to select only animal that are 2 year old (but i can do this :D )
Thank

Answer (score 6):

```
select sum(case when species = 'cat' then 1 else 0 end) as "Cat", 
       sum(case when species = 'dog' then 1 else 0 end) as "Dog", 
       sum(case when species = 'horse' then 1 else 0 end) as "Horse", 
       0 as "duck", 
       0 as "Mouse"
from animal
where species in ('cat', 'dog', 'horse')
```

Comment: I, thank you very much, i was trying your code, but the results are in two line, and i need that the results are in the same like "11 22 33 0 0", i wrong?

Comment: I wrong!!! i put group by species! when i cancel the group by work very Goood!!! :D :D :D thank you!!! :D :D :D

Comment: +1 Probably better than my solution, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I too think amazing that you're new here. :D

```
select
  (select count(*) from animal a where a.species = 'cat') as Cat,
  (select count(*) from animal a where a.species = 'horse') as Horse,
  (select count(*) from animal a where a.species = 'duck') as Duck
from
  dual
```

NB: `dual` is a system table that always has a single row. It is very convenient for tricks like this.

Comment: hI, thank! i try this code, but a have to put this select in a materialized view and more union all ... this change the structure of my select, and i have a little problem. :(

Comment: You query the table 3 times, where only 1 time is needed. a_horse_with_no_name has a better solution

Comment: Yes, that's why I upvoted his answer and left a comment there. By the way, Oracle is very smart in optimizing queries like this, so it's not actually executing three queries on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.
All you need to do is remove the group by clause :D

```
select count(countOfCat) as "Cat", count(countOfDog) as "dog", count(countOfHorse) as "horse", 0 as "duck", 0 as "Mouse"
from animal
where Birthdate in
        (...
         -- i think not important
         ...
        )
        and ( species= 'cat' or species= 'dog' or species= 'horse')
```

Comment: Really? i spend 2 hours for a group by? ohhhhhhhh thank  You to everyBody! This Page is fantastic! :D